# Using a two word element within a simple form collection

Tags: simple-form

I have a form built with simple_form, and I have a collection asking a user to search for multiple elements within a form.  However how I have it built, I have a space dividing each element within the collection. The problem that I'm having is that I need to have an element called `online` but I need it changed to `online feature`.

```
  = f.input :recognition, :required => "", prompt: "-- SELECT ONE --",  input_html: { class: "formStyling" }, collection: %w{Article Blog LinkedIn Magazine Online }, label: "How did you hear about us?", required: false
```

My question is, is there a specific way to tinker with what is posted in the collection that I have written to allow for two word entries to be used? and if so, how would you do it?

I've tried `#{"Online Search"}`, `['Online Search']`, `[Online Search]` which has not had much success

Answer (score 0):

So the solution to the problem is how you use the collection. If you focus on building the the collection elements as an array, it allows you to make those changes.

So, change it to

```
collection: [ "Article", "Blog", "LinkedIn", "Magazine", "Online Search", "Referral", "Twitter", "Other" ]
```

And that should do the trick!